# How to change Datetime formate without converting to string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that I'm trying to create a tsplot using seaborn, the first issue I'm having after converting my DateTime from string to a DateTime object is that the day had been automatically added.

The original data frame looks like this:

```
zillowvisualtop5.head()
Out[161]: 
        City_State     Year     Price
0     New York, NY  1996-04  169300.0
1  Los Angeles, CA  1996-04  157700.0
2      Houston, TX  1996-04   86500.0
3      Chicago, IL  1996-04  114000.0
6      Phoenix, AZ  1996-04   88100.0
```

(Note that the date is in year-month format)
After I covert it into DateTime object so that I could plot it using seaborn, I get the issue of having a date added after the month.

```
zillowvisualtop5['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(zillowvisualtop5['Year'], format= '%Y-%m')
zillowvisualtop5.head()
Out[165]: 
        City_State       Year     Price
0     New York, NY 1996-04-01  169300.0
1  Los Angeles, CA 1996-04-01  157700.0
2      Houston, TX 1996-04-01   86500.0
3      Chicago, IL 1996-04-01  114000.0
6      Phoenix, AZ 1996-04-01   88100.0
```

The solution that I've found seems to suggest converting to strftime but I need my time to be in DateTime format so I can plot it using seaborn.

Comment: I also tried converting it to period which looked like it solved the problem, however then I am unable to plot it.

Comment: You can create a new column for stringformatted date, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that you are having is that a DateTime object will always include all the components of a date object and a time object. There is no way to have a DateTime object that only has year and month info (source: [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)).

However, you can use the matplotlib converters like this:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.plotting import register_matplotlib_converters
import seaborn as sns

cols = ['City', 'Price', 'Month']
data = [['New York', 125, '1996-04'],
        ['New York', 79, '1996-05'],
        ['New York', 85, '1996-06'],
        ['Houston', 90, '1996-04'],
        ['Houston', 95, '1996-05'],
        ['Houston',127, '1996-06']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols)
print (df)

chart = sns.lineplot(x='Month', y='Price', hue='City', data=df)
```

[image]

Does that get the results you were looking for?

Comment: Sure, I'm trying to make a time series plot with time on the x-axis and price on the y-axis.  There should be one line for each of the cities.  I have done this already when my dataframe only has year.  But when it's in the year-month format, I get this error while plotting:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1996-04'
```

Comment: @Lee Thanks for clarifying, I hope the answer above works for you?

Comment: @ Roberto Moctezuma  Thank you very much for your help!  I guess I was approaching the problem wrong.  I am using tsplot by the way. I was able to get a plot in the beginning without removing the automatically added day and the plot looked really smooth, the only problem was that my x-axis label was wrong.  But now that I've removed the day using the method you've described, the graph looks very steplike which is weird and the label is off.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Your last edit works!  I switched over to using lineplot instead of tsplot.